# Issues with touchpad indicator

Tags: touchpad

Touchpad indicator is a lifesaver. However, there are several problems with that. Each time I unplug my mouse it doesn't reenable the touchpad. Also each time I shut the lid down on my laptop it disables the touchpad even if the touchpad was enabled before.  I have hit the shortcut keys to first disable and then hit it again to reenable. And then to get the effect of disabling the touchpad while typing. I have to go to preferences and click 'OK', exit the touchpad-indicator and restart it again. Anyway to fix this problem. What would be the command to restart the touchpad-indicator?

System Information
    Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Product Name: 20ENCTO1WW
    Version: ThinkPad P50

Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: In the Touchpad preferences, go to the Actions tab, and uncheck "Disable mousepad when mouse plugged" and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes but I want my touchpad to be disabled while the mouse is plugged in

Answer (score 1):

after some playing with xinput (xinput --list / xinput --list-props with_proper_id) I managed to fix this on same laptop/Ubuntu combination by changing python file /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/touchpad-indicator/share/touchpad-indicator/touchpad.py:

```
85,86d84
<       # fix - only "device enabled" was set before
<       ejecuta(('xinput set-prop %s "Synaptics Off" 0')%id)        
93,94d90
<       device_enabled = False
<       synaptics_off = True
98,106c94,95
<                   # fix
<                   #return True
<                   device_enabled = True
<           if line.lower().find('synaptics off')!=-1:
<               if line.split(':')[1].strip() == '0':
<                   synaptics_off = False
<       # fix - only "device enabled" was checked before
<       #return False
<       return device_enabled and not synaptics_off
---
>                   return True
>       return False
118c107
<           self.set_touchpad_enabled(id)
---
>           print(self.set_touchpad_enabled(id))
```

First diff is in method "set_touchpad_enabled" and second in "is_touchpad_enabled".

Changed methods should look like this:

```
    def set_touchpad_enabled(self,id):
            ejecuta(('xinput set-prop %s "Device Enabled" 1')%id)           
            ejecuta(('xinput set-prop %s "Synaptics Off" 0')%id)            

    def is_touchpad_enabled(self,id):
            lines = ejecuta('xinput --list-props %s'%id)
            device_enabled = False
            synaptics_off = True
            for line in lines.split('\n'):
                    if line.lower().find('device enabled')!=-1:
                            if line.split(':')[1].strip() == '1':
                                    device_enabled = True
                    if line.lower().find('synaptics off')!=-1:
                            if line.split(':')[1].strip() == '0':
                                    synaptics_off = False
            return device_enabled and not synaptics_off
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I added whole methods, that would probably make things easier.